# angular-chart.js custom color based on chart label values

Tags: chart.js, angular-chart, donut-chart

I'm integrating Doughnut Chart using [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#doughnut-chart) and I want to use custom color based on chart label value.

```
//Controller
    vm.labels = ["A", "B", "C"];
    vm.data = [1, 2, 3];

//HTML
    <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
                        chart-data="vm.data" 
                        chart-labels="vm.labels"                    
                        chart-options="options"
                        chart-colors = "colours"
                        chart-legend = "true" >
    </canvas>
```

and i'm setting the color like below

```
ChartJsProvider.setOptions({
       colours: ['#DD1C2C', '#E03E2D','#E35B2B'],
       responsive: true
});
```

It works perfect only if all A,B and C are there  (`A => #DD1C2C B=> #E03E2D` and `C=>#E35B2B`)

But for the following case

```
$scope.labels = ["A", "C"];
$scope.data = [1, 3];
```

`A => #DD1C2C` and `C=>#E03E2D`

Expected :  `A => #DD1C2C` and `C=>#E35B2B`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to fill the missing parts with empty string and 0 like

```
$scope.labels = ["A", "", "C"];
$scope.data = [1, 0, 3];
```